# Changing object origin to arbitrary point without origin_set()?

Tags: python, scripting, objects

Is there a way to change the origin of an object to an arbitrary point (via scripting) without using the operator origin_set()?  I.e., isn't there a method or property on the object to do this?

I know I can do it like this:

```
bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = pt
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR')
```

but this can get tedious, e.g., if I have other objects selected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could do something like this in *Edit mode*.

```
obj.data.transform(mathutils.Matrix.Translation(-new_origin))
obj.location += new_origin
```

I use it in [this addon](https://gist.github.com/zeffii/5879583) which sets the origin to the selected vertex, or median.

---

or as CoDEmanX points out

```
obj.data.transform(mathutils.Matrix.Translation(-new_origin))
obj.matrix_world.translation += new_origin
```

Comment: Note that `transform()` does nothing in *Edit Mode* (you could conditional use the bmesh module to translate the edit mesh). You might wanna use `obj.matrix_world.translation += new_origin` instead of `.location`. Not sure what you concern is about local coordinate @zeffii?

Comment: @CoDEmanX tell me why not `.location` ?

Comment: Because it's not always the final location IIRC (parenting, drivers etc. might cause it to differ from the final matrix' translation).

Comment: I wish I could give @CoDEmanX an additional check mark.  It sounds like this .location vs. .matrix_world issue could answer another problem I recently ran across.

Comment: Run Zeffi's answer in *Object Mode*, otherwise the transform action will be ignored and you'll just end up moving the origin and the geometry data. Tested successfully in Blender 2.83.

Comment: What format is expected for the offset value of `new_origin`? I tried several ways, such as `new_origin = [ 0.0, 0.0, -3.0 ]` but I get `TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'list'` I want to shift the origin by -3 on my object's local Z axis, while geometry stays put relative to the world. Thanks.

Comment: it would be a [mathutls.Vector()](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector)

Answer (score 5):

**Transform origin locally and object globally**

To set the origin of an objects mesh to the global location of the scene cursor while maintaining the global location of the vertices, calculate the local coordinate of cursor, transform the mesh by subtracting it from all vert coordinates.

Then move the object back by the vector difference of starting global location (matrix world translation) and cursor location.

Test script: run in object mode.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
ob = context.object
mw = ob.matrix_world
imw = mw.inverted()
me = ob.data

origin = scene.cursor.location
local_origin = imw @ origin
me.transform(Matrix.Translation(-local_origin))
mw.translation += (origin - mw.translation)
```

Note this will however move other objects that share the mesh.

For an edit mode version see

[Setting mesh's origin in python (2.8)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140605/setting-meshs-origin-in-python-2-8/140637)

Comment: Nice! Can your code be modified to resposition the origin along the object's local axes while leaving the mesh in place relative to the world? To move an object's origin 3.0 local Z (-3.0 relative to the mesh data) I modified a line of your code to: `me.transform(Matrix.Translation( (0.0, 0.0, -3.0) ))` but the object moves as well, and I don't know how to counter that offset.

Comment: Make the global location that of the local coord now the origin. `ob.matrix_world.translation = mw @ Vector((0, 0, -3))` ( Which is what last line above is doing.)

Comment: Thank you! With that knowledge I was able to get it working. Here's the full script for anyone who wants it: `import bpy` `from mathutils import Matrix` `from mathutils import Vector` `context = bpy.context` `scene = context.scene` `ob = context.object` `mw = ob.matrix_world` `imw = mw.inverted()` `me = ob.data` `offset = Vector((0, 0, 3))` `me.transform(Matrix.Translation( -offset ))` `ob.matrix_world.translation = mw @ offset`

Comment: the problem this is not taking into account rotation and with the option parent_only option I don't find how to do it