# How to center location of all objects?

Tags: python, 3d-cursor

All my object have their location at 0,0,0 I would prefer if they have their location in the center of the object.

I thought I could just select ht object, go into edit, snap the cursor to the center, go back to object mode and adjust the origin.
I always get the error `context is incorrect` for `snap_cursor_to_center()` but I am checking before that I am in the VIEW_3D. I am not sure what is meant by context error.

````py
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':

        for object in bpy.data.objects[:1]:  # only one for testing
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

            object.select_set(state=True)

            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')

            bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_center()  # ERROR :(

            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
            bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR')
```
````

Comment: For multiple objects, suggest iterate through the objects of the scene:  `bpy.context.scene.objects` instead of `bpy.data.objects` and use the python console to test, Cheers!

Comment: Might be useful as well [Changing object origin to arbitrary point without origin_set()?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/35825/31447)